# Shiny module: To return multiple reactive outputs from a single function in a module (linking a leaflet map and data table)

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, r-leaflet, shiny-reactivity

I'm coding a Shiny module to link a leaflet map with a data table (the code is based on [Shiny - how to highlight an object on a leaflet map when selecting a record in a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781380/shiny-how-to-highlight-an-object-on-a-leaflet-map-when-selecting-a-record-in-a)).

The difficulty I'm having is passing some rendered text ("tabvec_title") and a data table ("vector_table") from the module.R script to app. R, and linking the data table and leaflet map. This guideline is useful (https://github.com/rstudio/webinars/blob/master/19-Understanding-modules/01-Modules-Webinar.pdf) but it is still not clear to me how best to pass the rendered text and table to app.R. Many thanks for your advice. (updated see comment below).

Excerpts from the files:
**app.R (version 2):**

```
source("module.R")

tags$div(id="tabvec ",
  fluidRow(
  column(12,
    tags$br(),
       tags$div(myModuleUI('vector_titab'), id="myModuleUI")


server <- function(input, output, session) {
proxy <- leafletProxy("map")

callModule(mod_sl1,'vector_titab', reactive(input$pow_sl), proxy, vector_table, tabvec_title, 
   reactive(input$map_marker_click))

# Hide/show DT and title beneath map
 observe({
   if(input$pow_sl == TRUE){
     shinyjs::show(id="myModuleUI", selector = input$pow_sl)
   } else {
     shinyjs::hide(id="myModuleUI", selector = input$pow_sl)
   }}
 )
   ...
```

**module.R (version 2):**

```
# Permits interactive selection of marker and DT table rows ----
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

myModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textOutput(ns("tabvec_title")),
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("vector_table"))
  )
}

mod_sl1 <- function(input, output, session, pow_sl, prox, vector_table, tabvec_title, 
                map_marker_click){

 ns <- session$ns
 observeEvent(pow_sl(), {
 html_legend <- '<i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:green;"></i></i>Plants '
 print("test89")
 if(pow_sl() != 0){
    pow_sl <- readOGR("./geospatial_files/srilanka", layer = "plants")
    pow_sldf <- as.data.frame(pow_sl)

    # add table
    pow_d <- pow_sldf[,c(1:5,7:8,10:11,14)]
    pow_d$Latitude <- round(pow_d$Latitude, digits=4)
    pow_d$Longitude <- round(pow_d$Longitude, digits=4)
    colnames(pow_d)<- c("id","PlantName","Latitude", "Longitude","Type")
    pow_d$id <- as.character(pow_d$id)
    pow_d$Fuel <- as.character(pow_d$Fuel)
    pow_d$Type <- as.character(pow_d$Type)

    # drop first row with missing details
    pow_dt <- pow_d[-1,]

 output$tabvec_title <- renderText({ "Plants" })

 output$vector_table <- renderDataTable({
 DT::datatable(pow_dt, selection = c("single"),
                options=list(stateSave = TRUE, buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel',  'print'),dom = 'Bflit'),
                rownames=FALSE, caption = "", extensions = 'Buttons')
})

 # to keep track of previously selected row
 prev_row <- reactiveVal()

 # new icon style
 red_icon = makeAwesomeIcon(icon = 'flag', markerColor = 'red', iconColor = 'white')

 observeEvent(input$vector_table_rows_selected, {
   row_selected = pow_dt[input$vector_table_rows_selected,]
   prox %>%
     addAwesomeMarkers(
      layerId = as.character(row_selected$id),
      lng=row_selected$Longitude,
      lat=row_selected$Latitude,
      group = "pow_slg",
      icon = red_icon,
      label = as.character(row_selected$Fuel))

   # Reset previously selected marker
   if(!is.null(prev_row()))
   {
    prox %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(popup=as.character(prev_row()$Fuel),
                        layerId = as.character(prev_row()$id),
                        lng=prev_row()$Longitude,
                        lat=prev_row()$Latitude,
                        group = "pow_slg",
                        icon=icons_pow,
                        #icon = as.character(prev_row()$icons),
                        label = as.character(row_selected$Fuel))
  }
  # set new value to reactiveVal
  prev_row(row_selected)
  print("prev_row")
  print(prev_row)
})

prox %>%
  addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft", layerId="pow_slc") %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(
    data = pow_dt, 
    layerId = as.character(pow_dt$id),
    icon = icons_pow,
    group = "pow_slg",
    label = as.character(pow_dt$Fuel))

    observeEvent(map_marker_click(), {
    clickId <- map_marker_click()$id
    dataTableProxy("vector_table") %>%
    selectRows(which(pow_dt$id == clickId)) %>%
    selectPage(which(input$vector_table_rows_all == clickId) %/% input$vector_table_state$length + 1)
})

 } else {
  prox %>% clearGroup("pow_slg") %>% removeControl(layerId="pow_slc")
}
})
}
```

Comment: I've updated the above code which now displays the data table beneath the map. However there is one remaining issue: while selecting a row in the table highlights the map marker,  I've been unable to resolve  how to select a marker on the map which then highlights the corresponding row in the DT table. If there is a better way to code this I'd be pleased to learn.

Comment: Updated to now address above selecting marker and highlighting record in table.

Everything seems to work, but interested to learn if there is any alternative or better way of linking modules to the main app.R.